# SVG Scale group from his center

Tags: javascript, svg, css-transforms

I'm trying to scale an `<g></g>` called `#RectangleScaled` by a 1.4 factor from the group center.
I'm using this formula

```
translate(-centerX*(factor-1), -centerY*(factor-1)) scale(factor)
```

But the red rectangle doesn't seem to have the right translation

Here is my implementation

```
var rectangle = document.querySelector("#Rectangle")
var rectangleScaled = document.querySelector("#RectangleScaled")

var canvasBbox = document.querySelector("#Canvas").getBBox()

var x = -canvasBbox.width/2*(1.4-1)
var y = -canvasBbox.height/2*(1.4-1)

rectangleScaled.style.transform = "translate("+x+"px, "+y+"px) scale(1.4)"
```

Svg

```
<svg width="411" height="731" viewBox="0 0 411 731" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Canvas" transform="translate(721 384)">
    <clipPath id="clip-0" clip-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="Google Pixel" clip-path="url(#clip-0)">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>

      <g id="RectangleScaled">
        <use xlink:href="#path1_fill" transform="translate(-614 -152)" fill="red"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Rectangle">
        <use xlink:href="#path0_fill" transform="translate(-614 -152)" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
    <path id="path1_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s86scpw8/38/)

Comment: Could you clarify, what exactly would you like to do, because I don't get it? Just scale it but leave centered, or scale and move it?

Comment: I want to scale the red rectangle to 1.4 but I dont want it to move I only want it to scale from his center position, if you only try to do scale(1.4) you will see that the rectangle is scaling but also moving which is not what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have got your centre wrong.  You are scaling around the wrong centre point.

You are dividing `canvasBBox` `width` and `height` by two, but you are not taking into account the `x` and `y` values of the bbox.

The centre of the `#Canvas` element is at

```
var cx = canvasBbox.x + canvasBbox.width/2;
var cy = canvasBbox.y + canvasBbox.height/2;
```

If you update the calculation with these values, you get your expected result.

```js
var rectangle = document.querySelector("#Rectangle")
var rectangleScaled = document.querySelector("#RectangleScaled")

var canvasBbox = document.querySelector("#Canvas").getBBox()

var cx = canvasBbox.x + canvasBbox.width/2;
var cy = canvasBbox.y + canvasBbox.height/2;

var x = -cx * (1.4 - 1)
var y = -cy * (1.4 - 1)

rectangleScaled.style.transform = "translate("+x+"px, "+y+"px) scale(1.4)"
```

```html
<svg width="411" height="731" viewBox="0 0 411 731" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Canvas" transform="translate(721 384)">
    <clipPath id="clip-0" clip-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="Google Pixel" clip-path="url(#clip-0)">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>

      <g id="RectangleScaled">
        <use xlink:href="#path1_fill" transform="translate(-614 -152)" fill="red"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Rectangle">
        <use xlink:href="#path0_fill" transform="translate(-614 -152)" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
    <path id="path1_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only for Chrome** (consider it as a bug):
For scale and keep the scaled element in the center position you can do it with pure CSS, by adding `transform-origin: center;` style to `#RectangleScaled` selector.

```js
var rectangle = document.querySelector("#Rectangle")
var rectangleScaled = document.querySelector("#RectangleScaled")

var canvasBbox = document.querySelector("#Canvas").getBBox()


rectangleScaled.style.transform = "scale(1.4)"
```

```css
svg {
  border:solid;
}

#RectangleScaled {
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<svg width="411" height="731" viewBox="0 0 411 731" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Canvas" transform="translate(721 384)">
    <clipPath id="clip-0" clip-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="Google Pixel" clip-path="url(#clip-0)">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      
      <g id="RectangleScaled">
        <use xlink:href="#path1_fill" transform="translate(-614 -152)" fill="red"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Rectangle">
        <use xlink:href="#path0_fill" transform="translate(-614 -152)" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
    <path id="path1_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seems to be working, i keep seeing the red rectangles on the left

Comment: You also need transform-box: fill-box;

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rectangle = document.querySelector("#Rectangle")
var rectangleScaled = document.querySelector("#RectangleScaled")

var canvasBbox = document.querySelector("#Canvas").getBBox()
var s = 1.4; // you can change this value to scale
var cx = canvasBbox.x + canvasBbox.width/2;
var cy = canvasBbox.y + canvasBbox.height/2;

var x = (cx * -(s - 1)) * 1;
var y = (cy * -(s - 1)) * (10 * s);

rectangleScaled.style.transform = "translate("+x+"px, "+y+"px) scale("+s+")"
```

```css
svg {
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="411" height="731" viewBox="0 0 411 731" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Canvas" transform="translate(721 384)">
    <clipPath id="clip-0" clip-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="Google Pixel" clip-path="url(#clip-0)">
      <path d="M -721 -384L -310 -384L -310 347L -721 347L -721 -384Z" fill="yellow"/>
      
      <g id="RectangleScaled">
        <use xlink:href="#path1_fill" transform="translate(-620 -360)" fill="red"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Rectangle">
        <use xlink:href="#path0_fill" transform="translate(-620 -360)" fill="#C4C4C477"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
    <path id="path1_fill" d="M 0 0L 196 0L 196 266L 0 266L 0 0Z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).